# 20.04 Join Displays ordering not working

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, this weekend I accidentally removed ubuntu-desktop (after having trouble with python3, I removed it, which led to ubuntu-desktop being removed as well) which I have since reinstalled and seemed to be working fine, untill today.

When I connected my external monitor at work today, I noticed it wasn't configured correctly anymore. My external monitor is physically on the left of my laptops screen, but it was configured to be joined on the right.

When I try to change this setting in the display options, it only works in this configuration. Any other ordering of the screens (external monitor on the right, top or bottom of my laptops screen), it acts as if my two monitors are one big one. Maximizing any window using these settings will maximize it across both screens which is obviously not what I want. The pop up to confirm or revert the display settings is also displayed "in the middle" between the two screens, with one half on one display, and the other half on the other.

Comment: Changing or deleting the standard python version of Ubuntu is a unrecouverable error. You need to reinstall.

Boot from a live DVD or USB and reinstall. If your live DVD/USB is the same version as the installed Ubuntu version, you will see a "Reinstall" option. This will reinstall the system in the same setup as the existing installation, without formatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration will be preserved.

Comment: I will try this out, it has worked pretty much flawless except for the monitor issue, would be weird if that was the only manifestation of what you call an "unrecouverable error".

Comment: I tried booting using a live USB but there was no option to reinstall, as I'm using a dual boot. I also wasn't able to just reinstall be deleting my root folder only, because my /home is mounted on the same partition and that would mean losing all my data. I might reinstall at some point in the future

Comment: If it was the same media as first install the re install option would have come up.